# is it possible to use Arabic letter using laravel-dompdf?

Tags: laravel, pdf, fonts

Currently I'm facing one problem to create PDF that is support Arabic letters.
But all letters are revered when generate that. I'd like to use that.
Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the issue in laravel-dompdf. Use tcpdf-laravel instead of that.

Comment: I see. I thought that. Thanks

Comment: don't forget to specify to config in composer.json. you can specify what php version you are using.  `platform:{php:7.x}}`

Comment: how can I figure it out? sorry I'm new to here

Comment: delete composer.lock file and add that key and value in composer.json

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks

Comment: it will be helpful to update your laravel version and dependencies.

Comment: using that, can i update/donw dependencies versions?

Comment: using that, can i update/donw dependencies versions?

Comment: Of course. try that first so that you can notice how it works